# Python - generator (yield) in multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a use case where I have two jobs, called `cpu_operation` and `expensive_gpu_operation` that each one is CPU intensive and takes long time.

`expensive_gpu_operation`, depends on the outputs of `cpu_operation`. So given multiple process what I am trying to achieve, is when `expensive_gpu_operation` is working on task N, `cpu_operation` will already start working on N+1.

Without generators, this code works `cpu_operation` has no states, and executes from scratch each time - I need it to be a generator

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from time import sleep


def cpu_operation(task):
    print('START CPU TASK {}'.format(task))
    sleep(5)
    print('END CPU TASK {}'.format(task))
    return '-{}-'.format(task)

def expensive_gpu_operation(task):
    print('GPU TASK {}'.format(task))



def quick():
    pool = Pool(processes=1)
    results = []
    for task in range(5):
        cpu_result = cpu_operation(task)
        async_result = pool.apply_async(expensive_gpu_operation, (cpu_result, ))
        results.append(async_result)

    return [x.get() for x in results]
```

The problem here, is that the the `cpu_operation` is "stateless" and I need it to be a generator. Both methods `cpu_operation` and `expensive_gpu_operation` has to be "stateful", but the `expensive_gpu_operation` is "stateful" natively, because it runs on the main process which always lives.

How can I achieve that?

The solution in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614781/python-yield-in-multiprocessing-pool) seems to actually deplete the whole generator before returning the result - which is not what I aim for. I need each yielded value to be passed immediately to the `expensive_gpu_operation`